# Postgres: "Abstract" is-a relations / ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I gotta create some tables from the following ER diagram:
[image]

(not sure if the way I've done it is correct, so here's a short textual explanation:
Users can create 0-n Things, a Thing is created by a single User. Things consist of Subthings. A thing has at least one Subthing, and a Subthing is part of one Thing. Subthings are either made of Metal or Wood (XOR) - they're in a is-a relationship. Subthings are identified by their SubthingID and the ThingID belonging to it)

First of all, I'm really unsure on how to deal with the whole Subthing/Wood/Metal thing. Subthing is supposed to be "abstract", similar to abstract classes in OOP so that things are either made out of Wood or Metal, but not both. I also need the Subthing Entity later on, so I can't just remove it in favour of one of them.

I've come up with the following commands:

```
CREATE TABLE User1 (
    UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Thing (
    ThingID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    created_by INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES User1(UserID)
);

CREATE TABLE Subthing (
    consists_of INTEGER REFERENCES Thing(ThingID),
    SubthingID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SubthingID, consists_of)
);

CREATE TABLE Metal (
    Mstuff VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    SubthingID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Subthing(SubthingID),
    consists_of INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Subthing(consists_of),
    PRIMARY KEY (SubthingID, consists_of)
);


CREATE TABLE Wood (
    Wstuff VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    SubthingID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Subthing(SubthingID),
    consists_of INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Subthing(consists_of),
    PRIMARY KEY (SubthingID, consists_of)
);
```

However, when I try to run it with pgadmin3, I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "subthing"
>   ********** Error **********
>   
>   ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "subthing"

Now I'm really not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reference the complete PK constraint, you can't just reference a single column - not even if you do that for two columns individually.

You need to create a *single* FK constraint referencing *both* columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Metal (
    Mstuff VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    SubthingID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    consists_of INTEGER NOT NULL,
    foreign key (SubthingID, consists_of) 
       references subthing (SubthingID, consists_of) --<< ONE constraint with TWO columns
    PRIMARY KEY (SubthingID, consists_of)
);
```